# How can I do a helper inside other helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want make a helper how in this example

```
def textForm()
'<div class="form-group">
<%= f.label :nombre, :class => "col-md-3 control-label" %>
<div class="col-md-9">
<%= f.text_field :nombre, :class=> "form-control"%>
</div>
</div>'.html_safe
end
```

but... when I call this helper with <%= textForm %> just print html syntax.
apparently I need make something as "pre-render". Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try with <% textForm %> without = sign

Comment: what you mean by "pre-render"? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I think you're looking for partials much more than helpers, this is exactly what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Partial**

As mentioned in the comments, you'll be better using a [`partial`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) to sort this out:

```
 #app/views/controller/_your_partial.html.erb
 <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :nombre, :class => "col-md-3 control-label" %>
     <div class="col-md-9">
         <%= f.text_field :nombre, :class=> "form-control"%>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This will allow you to call the partial as follows:

```
<%= render partial: "controller/your_partial" %>
```

--

**Helper**

If you want to call HTML directly from a helper, [you should probably look at using the `raw` method](http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/how-to-display-html-tags-in-rails-helper-methods/):

```
<%= raw textForm %>
```

and then

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def textForm()
   '<div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :nombre, :class => "col-md-3 control-label" %>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= f.text_field :nombre, :class=> "form-control"%>
        </div>
    </div>'
end
```